# Intercepting clicked URL opening more than 1 instance

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I am trying to intercept a clicked URL to open my APP

```
<intent-filter>
    <data
        android:host="myurl.open"
        android:path="/import"
        android:scheme="http" />

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

**In MainActivity**

```
String linkClicked = getIntent().getDataString();
new AlertDialog.....
```

It almost works correctly but the problem is that:

> Every new clicked link it open a new instance of my app, but I don't want this, I want it to display in the same opened instance

**Example:**

click myurl.open/import?=1

Open the first instance showing the dialog that the user clicked in the link

click myurl.open/import?=2

Open the first instance and display the dialog showing the new clicked URL, but its opening a new instance, so I now have 2 running apks, and if I click in the third link it will open the third, how can I make it to open only the same?

If I click in the same URL again it open the first instance opened from this URL, but it doesn't display an `AlertDialog`

Comment: Try to add `android:launchMode="singleTask"` or `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` in your main activity tag.

Comment: @Rami that made the trick, but now the getIntent().getDataString() return null =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) To open a single instance of your app, use `android:launchMode="singleTask"` or `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in `AndroidManifest.xml` in your activity tag.

2) To get the data from the new intent, just override [onNewIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)) method:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent); // to attach the new intent to your Activity
    //now getIntent() will return the last data
}
```